# Headphones buttons don't operate on current app

Tags: audio, headphones

I have a Samsung s3 phone (rooted Cyanogenmod). I like to listen to audiobooks on Overdrive Media Console. I also have Poweramp installed for playing videos and songs. The problem I face is: Whenever I connect my headset and operate the play/pause buttons, they are intercepted by Poweramp, and not applied to Overdrive. Even if I've removed Poweramp from the currently running apps, using the headset buttons pops open Poweramp instead of playing/pausing the audiobook I'm currently listening to on Overdrive.

I wasn't able to find settings that would make the headset operate on the current app. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the playstore for "headset control". There are a bunch of apps available, partly for specific brands, but mostly working with all of them. I remember with some you could specify the app to send commands to. As a side-effect you can control a lot of actions using a kind of "morse code" with the single button, such as play/pause or prev/next or vol+/-, accept/reject incoming calls, and more.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a couple. They allow you to change the behavior of the buttons, but I wasn't able to specify the app it should control. It always controls Poweramp, not the app that is currently open.

Comment: Take a look at [Headset Droid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/headset-droid/tvk.headvol), 3rd screenshot, first item: *Target media player*. [Headset button controller](http://www.appbrain.com/app/headset-button-controllertrial/com.kober.headset), 5th screenshot: *music apps you want to control*. And so on. Doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the app. As suggested in the screenshot, I selected Overdrive in the apps to control. Now, the headset buttons don't pop up Poweramp, but they also don't play Overdrive. They've basically become non-functional.

Comment: As said, not all of those apps do necessarily work with all brands of buds (Jays e.g. didn't work well with my Philips headset). Try the other one, try a third (the two were just the examples I've found within 20secs, there are much more), try with different music players. Play around a bit IMHO is the best you can do.